# HighchartsReact yAxis: How to display only rounded number?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I have a HighchartsReact graph.
the numbers on the `yAxis` scale are displayed as Decimal number (0, 0.5 , 1, 1.5, 2 ...).
I would like to display only the rounded numbers (0, 1, 2 ...).
I tried to add the code below:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        format: '{value:.0f}'
    }
},
```

but now the numbers are displayed with duplicates (0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 ...).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
yAxis: {
    allowDecimals: false
},
```